# Finding json attribute by wildard with jq

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I am trying to find a way to extract JSON attributes using wildcard selection with jq. Is there any way to do it? I have the following JSON file.  The fields can be dynamic for each system. I want to map Core with its "input" temperature (tempX_input).

```json
{
  "Core 0": {
    "temp2_input": "52.000",
    "temp2_max": "100.000",
    "temp2_crit": "100.000",
    "temp2_crit_alarm": "0.000"
  },
  "Core 1": {
    "temp3_input": "53.000",
    "temp3_max": "100.000",
    "temp3_crit": "100.000",
    "temp3_crit_alarm": "0.000"
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```json
{
  "Core 0": "52.000",
  "Core 1": "53.000"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression :

```
jq 'map_values(
        to_entries[] |
        select(.key |
                test("temp[[:digit:]]+_input")).value
    )' input.json
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan That would select keys like "temp_hello_world_input".

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
with_entries(.value |= (with_entries(select(.key | endswith("_input"))) | to_entries[].value ))
```

Using `with_enries` so we can get the desired keys using `endswith("_input")`

---

The above will generate:

```json
{
  "Core 0": 52,
  "Core 1": 53
}
```

As you can test in [this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JNlUdiA8UO)